# Why TypeScript flow analysis doesn't cover else block?

Tags: typescript, types, static-analysis

Let's consider the following code:

```js
function f(x : number) {
    if (x === 1) {
        if (x === 2) {} // error
    }
    else {
        if (x === 1) {} // OK
    }
}
```

Here, the compiler gives me an error on `x === 2`.
The reason is simple: if execution has reached this block then `x` should be `1` as `x === 1` passed.
And since `1` and `2` have no overlap it is impossible for `x` to be both `1` and `2`.

But the compiler is totally OK with the second `x === 1` inside the `else`.
This should not be possible as `x` has already failed check for `x === 1` in the `if` statement.
And since `x` cannot satisfy both `x === 1` and `!(x === 1)` the second `if` should give me the same error as for `x === 2`.

How is this possible?
Is this some kind of not implemented feature of advanced flow analysis? Is this a bug?
Or maybe this case have some hidden logic and in the end it does have some sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Typescript isn't capable of expressing a *not* type, such as `number` but *not* a specific number.

When you do:

```
if (x === 1) { x } // x is type: 1
```

Then it knows `x` is `1` in that block. This is fine, `1` is valid and useful type. And it's trivial to statically say that `1 === 2` can never be true.

But in the else block here:

```
if (x === 1) { x }
else { x } // x is type: number
```

Then `x` is type `number`, because the type system cannot express "all numbers except `1`". So the compiler cannot actually guarantee that code path cannot be taken, even though you can see that.

---

It's a limitation of the type system, sure. But Typescript isn't perfect. It's a type system on top of a different language, and this one of those things where you're going have to settle for good enough.

Comment: I believe they don't intend on implementing "not" types either, since they aren't that useful most of the time...

Comment: @vera.
I don't agree on "aren't useful".
Functions like `divide(x : number, y : number & not 0)` will definitely benefit from these.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer, Ok, they aren't useful *enough* that the team would want to implement them. Also, as for your example, what if someone did `divide(2, 0 as number)`? Should `number` be assignable to `number & not 0`? Sometimes you would want `T`, where `T` is a supertype of `U`, to be assignable to `T & not U`, and sometimes you don't... which can cause headaches.

Comment: @vera., I'm don't think that `number` can be assigned to `number & not 0`. But I agree that at least in some cases this level of typing might "cause headaches". On the other side TypeScript already have these kind of issues in other use cases, so in the end the introduction of `not` type might not make the language worst than before.

Comment: @vera., in the end, the introduction of such a feature should have place in some language in the future. This means better types, and better types means safer programs.
The sooner this will be introduced in any language - the sooner humanity will have a crucial feedback on pros and cons of this feature.
This will help future languages be better sooner. So I will be very happy if TS team decide to implement `not` type soon or at least put in into a wishlist.